# scrapy error in image processing

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to download images using scrapy but i am getting error ...i know the issue but i don't know how to solve it...here is [link](http://images.styletagassets.com/attachments/98315/product/WTSMIC0003_2.jpg?1368772608) for the image

And as their is some sort of ID is associated with the URL like : `jpg?1368772608`

I am getting this error :

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1423, in save
    raise KeyError(ext) # unknown extension
exceptions.KeyError: '.jpg?1368772608'
```

can some one tell how i can solve this issue

Comment: How do i remove that part after `?` so that `PIL` can recognize the image extension....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes that part after ? so that PIL can recognize the image extension:

```
>>> url = 'http://images.styletagassets.com/attachments/98315/product/WTSMIC0003_2.jpg?1368772608'
>>> url.split('?')[0]

'http://images.styletagassets.com/attachments/98315/product/WTSMIC0003_2.jpg'
```

Comment: Sure, but this is an image url.

Answer (score 0):

This defines a function which returns the corrected url. It allows for `?` to be present in the url without being removed. You can click [**here**](http://images.styletagassets.com/attachments/98315/product/WTSMIC0003_2.jpg) to test my outputted url.

```
import re
url = r"http://images.styletagassets.com/attachments/98315/product/WTSMIC0003_2.jpg?1368772608"
def fix(url):
    return re.match("(.+?)(?=\?\d+)",url).group()
print(fix(url))
>>> 
http://images.styletagassets.com/attachments/98315/product/WTSMIC0003_2.jpg
```